# Noether Current and Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, electric-current, field-theory, noethers-theorem

My question is simple. Assume that there is no anomaly and we have found from the lagrangian that there is a conserved current. I want to know what this means in terms of feynman diagrams, not in terms of operator equations (but it doesn't harm to write them either). Also is it always required that noether current current is coupled to a physical field ?

Comment: What do you mean "what this means in terms of feynman diagrams"? The Noether current is a conserved quantity (up to contact terms, cf. Ward-Takahashi), Feynman diagrams are a way to compute expectation values of polynomials in the fields. If the Noether current is a suitable polynomial in the fields, you may of course expand the Ward-Takahasi identity in the perturbative series of Feynman diagrams. For the last part, *gauge currents* are coupled to their respective gauge fields by a theorem of Weinberg, general Noether currents are not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am asking is the following, for example assume that I have found a a noether current in terms of the fields in the lagrangian. What does that mean in terms of S-matrix ? That is my question.